# how to repeat the elements of a 2d array n times without converting it to a list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, repeat

I have an array of `a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`
I am looking for a way to repeat each element for a certain times (lets say 3 times) to get the following array

```
b = [[1  2]
     [1  2]
     [1  2]
     [3  4]
     [3  4]
     [3  4]]
```

Is there a function to do this in numpy array directly or should I convert it to a list and multiply it and again convert it into an array?

Comment: have you tried `a.repeat(3, 0)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
b = np.repeat(a, 3, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

n_repeat = 3
b = np.tile(a, n_repeat).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
```